# This site can’t be reached in kubernetes minikube macbook

Tags: reactjs, kubernetes, deployment, service, minikube

I applied my react kubernetes manifest file on minikube with the service

I am trying to access it on the browser but I am getting error

This site can’t be reached

deployment.yml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: frontend
  labels:
    app: frontend
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: frontend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: frontend
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: frontend
          image: arch-frontend:1.0
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000
          env:
            - name: REACT_APP_DEV_BASE_URL
              value: backend
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
```

serivce.yml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: frontend
spec:
  selector:
    app: frontend
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
      nodePort: 30012
  externalIPs:
    - 192.168.64.2
```

I tried to access it on the browser using 192.168.64.2:30012 and 192.168.64.2:3000 but none worked

I did minikube servvice service-name still did not work

Comment: Are the pods running fine?

Comment: Yes the pods are running fine @rock'nrolla

Comment: Have you checked whether there are any firewall rules blocking your application from reaching the browser. Follow this [link](https://support.apple.com/en-in/guide/mac-help/mh34041/mac) for validating your firewall settings in mac os.

Comment: @etranz since you have found this comment useful for better visibility of the community I’m converting it to an answer and adding a few more points, revert back if you are still facing any issues.

Answer (score 0):

In general when you are deploying workloads on a personal computer, there are chances for a firewall to block your application ports from reaching outside. To mitigate this issue you have to check the firewall rules and add them if required.

This [**official macOS documentation**](https://support.apple.com/en-in/guide/mac-help/mh34041/mac) contains information on how to manage firewall rules, go through this documentation and make necessary changes so that you can access your application using the browser.

Also as per the [**official minikube documentation**](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/#example-of-nodeport) sometimes Node IP might not be reachable directly in such scenarios you need to create a tunnel for your NodePort service using minikube. Follow the below steps taken from official docs for creating the tunnel using the minikube command:

> **minikube service (service name) --url**